# In FFmpeg .wav to .wav conversion Header files are not matching

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-conversion, wav

By using below command changing the channel map but after successful run input wav file header is not matching with an output

```
ffmpeg -i in.wav -af "channelmap=13|14|15|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12" out.wav
```

Comment: Which software is complaining about the header? And what's the error msg?

Comment: I am checking both the files in HexPad

Comment: ffmpeg will usually add a info chunk with encoder info. Why do the headers need to match?

Comment: Is there any chance to avoid this?

Comment: We can avoid some metadata, yes, but since I don't know what your source header looks like, I don;t know if ffmpeg can match it.

Comment: by using flag -bitexact, avoided some bytes. but I need to avoid all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96519/discussion-between-varadaraju-g-and-gyan).